# SQL select rows with filters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+----+----------+
| id | feature  |
+----+----------+
| 1  |   10     |
| 1  |   20     |
| 2  |   20     |
| 3  |   40     |
| 4  |   50     |
| 5  |   60     |
+----+----------+
```

And I'd like to have the id's that have both features 10 and 20. So, not just the results that have 10 or 20, but I'd like to have the result of the id's that have both 10 and 20.

Comment: Use and clause after whare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to `GROUP BY` the `id` and use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table_name
WHERE feature IN (10,20)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(distinct feature) = 2
```

Comment: And what's about `6 10 | 6 10` ? It will be selected too

Comment: Thats a pretty good question you need to use having sum() see the answer from Khalid

Comment: @splash58 op has provided only sample data not table definition and there should be a unique compound index on (id,feature)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you can also add `HAVING COUNT(distinct feature ) = 2` [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbf10b/3) i guess you just forgot :)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Maybe, i don't know :)

Comment: Right distinct should do the job but having sum() looks sexy though :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to select the id that have features 10 and 20 you can do so

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having sum(feature = 10)
and sum(feature = 20)
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbf10b/1)

Comment: @OP check this answer it solves the question you asked me in my answer !

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do that

```
SELECT ID,
stuff(
(
    select ','+ convert(varchar,feature) from table where Id = t.Id for XML path('')
),1,1,'') [comma_sep_feature]
FROM [table] t 
group by id
```

you can insert this value in #temp and add where clause comma_sep_feature = '10, 20' like below

```
SELECT ID,
        stuff(
        (
            select ','+ convert(varchar,feature) from yourtable where Id = t.Id for XML path('')
        ),1,1,'') [comma_sep_feature]
        into #tem
        FROM [yourtable] t 
        group by id

    select * from #tem where comma_sep_feature = '10,20'

    drop table #tem
```